# Assigning value to a specific column and row in R

Tags: r

I have a data frame as below.

```
Name Amount Subscriptionperiod(Months)  Subscriptionstart (Month)
Tom  300    3                             0
Tom  100    3                             2
Jim  500    5                             0
Jim  600    3                             1
```

I would like to arrange the data like below. For example Tom paid 300$ for 3 months in one transaction. And in a second transaction 2 months later he paid additional 100$ for 3 months.

Similarily for Jim.

```
Name   M0   M1  M2   M3  M4  M5  M6
Tom    300 300  300  0   0   0   0
Tom    0    0   100  100 100 0   0
Jim    500 500  500  500 500 0   0
Jim    0   600  600  600 0   0   0
```

I'm not able to transform. I use the code below to do the first part. But how do I create a second row where the value starts from M2 in the case of Jim. 100$ to start from M2 and continue till M4.

```
for(i in 0:6) df <- within(df,assign(paste0("M",i),ifelse((Subscriptionperiod>i),amount,0)))
```

The code above gives the following output which is not what I want. Help would appreciated.

```
     Name   M0   M1  M2   M3  M4  M5  M6
    Tom    300 300  300  0   0   0   0
    Tom    100  100 100  0   0   0   0
    Jim    500 500  500 500 500  0   0 
    Jim    600  600  600 0   0   0   0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the data.table and plyr packages to achieve this.

```
library(data.table)
library(plyr)

df <- data.table(read.table(text='Name Amount Period  Start
                                   Tom  300    3      0
                                   Tom  100    3      2
                                   Jim  500    5      0
                                   Jim  600    3      1', header=T, row.names = NULL))
#Create a row by repeating df$Amount, df$Period times and padding with 0
create_rows <- function(x, y){
  c(rep(0, x$Start), rep(x$Amount, x$Period), rep(0, y - x$Period - x$Start))
}

#Create a new data.table and add Name column
df2 <- data.table(Name = df$Name)

#Create an array of month names
months <- paste('M', 0:6, sep = '')

#Use adply (from plyr) to apply create_rows() accross all rows of df2
#.expand = FALSE ensures the size of the returned data.frame is the right size
#.id = NULL stops adply() from creating an index column
#with = FALSE allows the variable month to be used to refer to columns
df2[, months := adply(df, 
                      1, create_rows,
                      length(months), 
                      .expand = FALSE, 
                      .id =NULL),
    with = FALSE]
```

Comment: instead of `paste(..., sep = '')`, you can also use `paste0(...)`

Comment: Will this work across a dataframe? As my source is a frame.

Comment: You'd need to turn your data into a data.table using setDT(df) first. Data.table is designed to be an extension for data.frame. With a few exceptions the data frame operations will still work and if necessary it is simple to transform back via setDF().

Comment: @NGaffney hey I'm getting this error Error in rep(0, y - x$period - x$periodstart) : invalid 'times' argument

Comment: I modified the column names when importing the data so maybe that's it. What happens when you paste and run the code, including the data import?

Comment: Your comment seems to have been cut off there. The y variable is the number of months (used for padding of following zeros in each row) and is passed to the function in the "length(months)," part of the call to adply.

Comment: its really frustrating, it works on your dataset but my larger dataset returns the invalid times argument. Can I share my code with you on email for help.

Comment: Ok i think i figured out the problem y-period-periodstart is returning -ve value. Because I have entries who's subscription period is beyond this month.

Comment: Nice catch. If you need further help you could edit the question but you you'll likely get better exposure if you post a new one with another data set which better matches your real data.

Answer (score 2):

```
text1="Name Amount Subscriptionperiod(Months)  Subscriptionstart(Month)
Tom  300    3                             0
Tom  100    3                             2
Jim  500    5                             0
Jim  600    3                             1"

df1 <- read.table(text=text1, head=T, as.is=T)

df2.lst <- apply(df1, 1, function(x){
  times <- x[3]
  lst <- lapply(1:times, function(i){return(x[1:2])})
  df.lst <- as.data.frame(do.call(rbind, lst))
  df.lst$mon <- paste0("M", seq(from=as.numeric(x[4]), 
                            length.out = as.numeric(x[3])))
  return(df.lst)
})

df2 <- do.call(rbind, df2.lst)

library(reshape2)
df2$mon <- factor(df2$mon, levels = paste0("M", 0:6))
df3 <- dcast(df2, Name+Amount~mon, value.var = "Amount")
df3$Amount <- NULL
df3
#   Name   M0   M1  M2   M3   M4
# 1  Tom  300  300 300 <NA> <NA>
# 2  Tom <NA> <NA> 100  100  100
# 3  Jim  500  500 500  500  500
# 4  Jim <NA>  600 600  600 <NA>
```

Comment: You can change all the NAs to 0 using `df3[is.na(df3)] <- 0`

Answer (score 2):

First, let's start with your minimal data frame:

```
df1 <- data.frame(name=c("Tom", "Tom", "Jim", "Jim"), amount=c(300, 100, 500, 600), 
                  Subperiod=c(3, 3, 5, 3), SubStart = c(0, 2, 0, 1))

> df1
  name amount Subperiod SubStart
1  Tom    300         3        0
2  Tom    100         3        2
3  Jim    500         5        0
4  Jim    600         3        1
```

Next, instantiate an empty matrix where `ncol` is equal to the # of months you want to show:

```
m <- matrix(0, nrow=4, ncol=7)
```

Now the clever part - make a function that will create a large vector to fill in the matrix based off of your rules

```
special_spread <- function(df1){
    bigrow <- c()
    for(i in 1:nrow(df1)){
      pt1 <- rep(0, df1$SubStart[i])
      pt2 <- rep(df1$amount[i], df1$Subperiod[i])
      pt3 <- rep(0, ncol(m) - (length(pt2)+length(pt1)) )
      bigrow <- c(bigrow, pt1, pt2, pt3)
    }
    m1 <- as.data.frame(matrix(bigrow, nrow=4, ncol=7, byrow = TRUE))
    m1 <- cbind(df1$name, m1)
    colnames(m1) <- c("name", paste0("M", 0:6))
    return(m1)
}

> special_spread(df1)
  name  M0  M1  M2  M3  M4 M5 M6
1  Tom 300 300 300   0   0  0  0
2  Tom   0   0 100 100 100  0  0
3  Jim 500 500 500 500 500  0  0
4  Jim   0 600 600 600   0  0  0
```

Please, let me know if this needs more explanation of if this more or less answers your question.

Comment: getting an error  Error in matrix(special(df1), nrow = 4, ncol = 7, byrow = TRUE) : 
  could not find function "special"

Comment: @Vaibhav try it now, I replaced `special(df1)` with `bigrow`. Typo on my part.